# Ionic with Angular 2

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic-v1

I am an Android Developer, I have been developing Android apps for a long time, but now I am asked in the company to start developing hybrid mobile applications with Ionic.

As I always do, I searched in Udemy and picked the top-rated courses in Angular2 and Ionic2 because the instructor of the Ionic course said that Angular 2 is a prerequisite for Ionic (given that I know HTML, CSS, Javascript), but I found that the Ionic documentation says I should learn AngularJs. Another thing that made me more confused is that in Udemy most of the courses teach Ionic with Angular 2 or 4 and only very few take the AngularJs Approach and even those few lack the quality available in the Angular Courses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ionic framework is just an UI framework for the hybrid mobile apps,
it uses AngularJs/Angular as core framework,

Ionic v1 uses AngularJs and Ionic v2+ uses Angular v2+,

an example for that if your are using the latest Ionic v3+ you will find the core functionality is in Angular v5.2+.

I recommend to use Angular v2+ with Ionic v2+ because it's the future of the web/hybrid technology. you will find yourself learning ES6, Typscript out of the box when you are using Angular v2+.

You can start with this tow courses:
https://www.udemy.com/the-complete-guide-to-angular-2/learn/v4/overview
https://www.udemy.com/ionic-2-the-practical-guide-to-building-ios-android-apps/learn/v4/overview

Hope I make things a little clearer.

Comment: That is a relief, Thank you very much that is really helpful.

Comment: another important note.. Ionic v4 (not yet released) is supposed to be template agnostic

Comment: Please can you tell me what u mean by template agnostic @SurajRao

Comment: @Armstring meaning you can use it with any template engine like vue/react/ember/angularjs(v1) etc.. read https://blog.ionicframework.com/ionic-2017-18-roadmap/

Comment: @SurajRao Thank u for the excellent RoaMap , really helped me not just the Ionic4 Part, the whole RoadMap is great, I recommend it to any one new to Ionic like myself.

Comment: @PeterWilson I did not realize the courses you suggested yesterday, sorry for that, those are exactly the courses I am asking about. What a coincidence:)